# quick view on product listing page

Tags: magento-1.9

How can you create a quick-view on product listing page for each individual product?

I have looking on this site and haven't seen anything.

Comment: Is there anything you tried? This question has no specifics.

Comment: @pspahn I am trying to find a script or a good extension, but I don't know where to ask that question with out getting blocked.

Comment: Did you try asking on Google? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=magento%20quick%20view%20extension

Comment: @pspahn.  Am I in right place?  Am I asking a magento related question? For your information, Google would send me back here.  If you don't know the answer, **DON'T answer!**

Comment: If you are looking for an extension, Google will give you plenty of them to choose from. If you want a recommendation for one, you are in the wrong place. If you would like to know how to build one, then ask a specific question about a certain technique you are trying. You have put zero effort into finding the answer so you should expect a similar amount of effort in response.

Comment: FYI @user2039247 just answered it.  Not you. Now go do something positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What information do you specifically want?

If you manage an attribute through the admin panel, you can set used in product listing to yes, this makes that data accessible to product list throught

```
$_product->getAttributeName();
```

Then you can use `jquery/bootstrap modal` to `show/hide` this information as a quickview based on a btn/link click event e.g.

```
$('#quick-view').on('click', function () {show/hide });
```

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you I will do that.